# Flutter: Dynamically update items of GridView.builder later in code after they have been created

Tags: flutter, dart, gridview, flutter-getx

I've added 3 Containers with GridView.builder on '+' button press.

Here is my GridView.builder code:

```
Obx(
  () => GridView.builder(
    itemCount: c.gridItems.length,
    shrinkWrap: true,
    gridDelegate:
        SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
            crossAxisCount: 4,
            crossAxisSpacing: 20.dp,
            mainAxisSpacing: 10.dp,
            mainAxisExtent: 60.dp),
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
      final isCurrentContainer =
          (index == c.audioPlayerCurrentIndex % 3);
      Color containerColor = isCurrentContainer
          ? Colors.blue
          : Colors.grey;

      return GestureDetector(
        onTap: () { 

          showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                StatefulBuilder(
              builder: (context, state) => KeysDialog(),
            ),
          );
        },
        child: Obx(
          () => Container(
            width: 60.dp,
            height: 60.dp,
            color: containerColor,
            child: Center(
              child: Text(
                c.gridItems[index],
                style: white22TextStyle,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    },
  ),
```

Here is my Controller. I'm using getX:

```
class Controller extends GetxController {
  var gridItems = [].obs;

  var isMetronomeSelected = false.obs;
  var isBassSelected = false.obs;
  var isDrumsSelected = false.obs;

  var tonalitySelected = 'Major'.obs;
  var keySelected = 'A'.obs;
  var rhythmsFolderSelected = 'Slow Dancing'.obs;
  var bpmSliderValue = 95.0.obs;

  var assetSources = [].obs;
  var audioPlayerCurrentIndex = 0;
  var audioPlayerLoopCount = 0.obs;
}
```

I want to change the Container's color based on currently playing sound(Container) when play button is pressed. I'm calling **this playAudio() method** on play button's onPress:

```
Future<void> playAudio() async {
    await audioPlayer
        .play(AssetSource(c.assetSources[c.audioPlayerCurrentIndex]));
    print(c.assetSources.length);
    print(c.assetSources);

    await audioPlayer.onPlayerComplete.first;

    c.audioPlayerLoopCount.value++;

    // Check if all audios have played the same number of times
    if (c.audioPlayerLoopCount.value == c.assetSources.length) {
      c.audioPlayerLoopCount.value = 0;

      c.audioPlayerCurrentIndex = 0;
      playAudio();
    } else {
      // Play the next audio
      c.audioPlayerCurrentIndex =
          (c.audioPlayerCurrentIndex + 1) % c.assetSources.length;
      playAudio();
    }
  }
```

I want to compare audioPlayerCurrentIndex with index of GridView items but index of those items is not updated on play button call. So it remains '2' always once I've created 3 Containers.

Am I missing something simple?

Answer (score 1):

The issue might be related to the way you're managing the state of the audioPlayerCurrentIndex within the Controller.

To ensure that changes in audioPlayerCurrentIndex trigger a rebuild of the GridView.builder. For that you need to explicitly mark it as observable within the Controller. You can use RxInt for this purpose:

```
class Controller extends GetxController {
  var gridItems = [].obs;

  // Define audioPlayerCurrentIndex as RxInt
  var audioPlayerCurrentIndex = 0.obs;

  // Other variables...
}
```

In view:

```
  Future<void> playAudio() async {
  // ... Your existing code ...

  // Update audioPlayerCurrentIndex when audio is played
  c.audioPlayerCurrentIndex.value =
  (c.audioPlayerCurrentIndex.value + 1) % c.assetSources.length;

  playAudio();
}
```

This change should ensure that when audioPlayerCurrentIndex changes, the Obx widget observing it will trigger a rebuild, updating the UI accordingly, including the colors of the containers in the GridView.builder based on the current audio being played.